# HOW to get SUM and COUNT using aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table like below

```
SCHEME  BROKNO  BRANNO  ACCNO   TYPE    SCAMT   FUNAMT  MONTH
AFS       123    345    125635  RN       130     140    11
AFS       123    345    125635  RN       130     140    11
AFS       123    345    125635  RN       145     185    11
AFS       123    345    125635  RN       130     140    11
AFS       123    345    125635  RN       180     220    10
AFS       123    345    125635  RN       200     260    10
AFS       123    345    125635  RN       180     220    10
AFS       123    345    125635  RN       180     220    10
```

Now I have to create report based on Month column and based on group (SCHEME,   BROKNO, BRANNO, ACCNO,  TYPE).

Report it should be

```
SCHEME BROKNO BRANNO ACCNO TYPE SUM(SCAMT) SUM(FUNAMT) MONTH11CNT   
AFS    123    345   125635 RN    535            605      4         

SUM(SCAMT) SUM(FUNAMT) MONTH11CNT 
740         920           4
```

I have tried with case statement, But I am getting same count for all group of records. Please someone give me idea.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you simply want to group by scheme, brokno, branno, accno, type and month:

```
select 
  scheme, brokno, branno, accno, type, month, 
  sum(scamt), sum(funamt), count(*) as monthcnt
from mytable
group by scheme, brokno, branno, accno, type, month;
```

EDIT: If you want to show the months in columns, you must know the months beforehand and write the query accordingly:

```
select 
  scheme, brokno, branno, accno, type,
  sum(case when month = 10 then scamt end) as month10scamt,
  sum(case when month = 10 then funamt end) as month10funamt,
  sum(case when month = 10 then 1 end) as month10cnt,
  sum(case when month = 11 then scamt end) as month11scamt,
  sum(case when month = 11 then funamt end) as month11funamt,
  sum(case when month = 11 then 1 end) as month11cnt
from mytable
where month in (10,11)
group by scheme, brokno, branno, accno, type;
```

Comment: I need it for count for each set of month .

Comment: What is a "set of month"? You see you got three answers and they are all the same. So how is what you want different from our answers?

Comment: As you commented Raj's answer with "Each month should be a separate column in a report" I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I have done the same thorsten, but I am getting multiple record set for each group. Its like for each month separate row set is coming.

Comment: You are saying that with the second query, you still get two or more rows for the same scheme, brokno, branno, accno, type? That cannot be.

Comment: No, I am getting it. Now I used CTE then MAX function its working fine now.

Comment: 1. If you group by scheme, brokno, branno, accno, and type and then get two result lines for the same scheme, brokno, branno, accno, and type, then your dbms is broken. GROUP BY ... means "I want one result line per ...". 2. Using a CTE (as long as it is not recursive) is just another way to write the same query, so I see no point in using it here. 3. MAX on what? All expresions are either grouped-by columns or aggregations already, so adding MAX on any of these expressions doesn't change anything.

Comment: Please don't misunderstand. I am glad you found a solution; I just wanted to mention that the way you describe your problem and solution makes no sense. So look at it once more and try to find out what you may have missed to tell us or what you failed to describe precisely, in order to learn from it and get better help next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get the results you want

```
SELECT 
  SCHEME,
  BROKNO,
  BRANNO,
  ACCNO,
  TYPE,
  SUM(SCAMT) As SCAMTTOTAL,
  SUM(FUNAMT) AS FUNAMTTOTAL,
  MONTH As MONTHNAME,
  COUNT(MONTH) AS MONTHCOUNT
FROM MyTABLE
GROUP BY
  SCHEME,
  BROKNO,
  BRANNO,
  ACCNO,
  TYPE,
  MONTH
```

If you need the results in a single row, then it would just be a matter of converting this to a CTE and querying that.

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7a0d1/4)

Comment: Each month should be a separate column in a report

Answer (score 0):

assuming, you want to count the rows within each month, one solution is to take the month into the aggregation as well:

```
select SCHEME, BROKNO, BRANNO, ACCNO, TYPE, MONTH,
       sum(SCAMT),
       sum(FUNAMT),
       Count(*) as MONTHCOUNT
from table
group by SCHEME, BROKNO, BRANNO, ACCNO, TYPE, MONTH
```

Comment: Each month should be a separate column in a report